# Ajax success function not executing after getting response

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

Following is my code:

```
$(".simpleCart_shelfItem button").click(function() {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $(this).html("Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-spinner9 spin'></i>");

            var action = "add";
            var queryString = "action="+action+"&pid="+this.value;

            $.ajax({
                    url: "add_cart",
                    data: queryString,
                    type: "POST",
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data == 1)
                            {
                                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                                $(this).removeClass('disabled');
                                $(this).html("Added In Cart");
                            }
                    },
                    error:function (){}
                });
        });
```

I am having 6 products on a page. If a user click on Add To Cart button for a particular product then this code will execute and send request to server.

The code is executing fine, i am even getting the response.

Problem is this even after getting the response the success function is not executuing i.e this code is not executing..

```
$(this).prop('disabled', false);
$(this).removeClass('disabled');
$(this).html("Added In Cart");
```

It only executes the code which it was meant on entering the click function i.e this code:

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
$(this).addClass('disabled');
$(this).html("Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-spinner9 spin'></i>");
```

And then it freezez on the above code.

The success function is not being executed.

Comment: Define "it freezes".  When you debug this in the browser, what specifically happens?  What is the actual response from the server?  When debugging in the browser, what *exactly* does `data` contain?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't executing? Are you sure it isn't just not having any effect?

Comment: data contains `1` from server side i have done `echo true` i.e the data has now value `1`

Comment: That doesn't prove the code isn't running. if the code IS running and having no effect, your question is a duplicate.

Comment: have you tried with a simple alert or console.log  first to ensure the success function ?

Comment: Yes m sure when i am `alert(data)` it even shows the response but the code isn't executing maybe i am missing something

Comment: Then you are in fact sure that it IS executing the code.

Comment: Does it have to do binding with data or something cause this is referring here in ajax call or something

Comment: Yes but this code is not executing after getting the response `$(this).prop('disabled', false);
                                $(this).removeClass('disabled');
                                $(this).html("Added In Cart");`

Comment: Yes it is. It just isn't having any effect because `this` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, when you declare a function inside an ajax call, the reference for the clicked element is lost.

So, replace the $(this) call inside the function of ajax success for $(".simpleCart_shelfItem button").

I think this will work.

Comment: Yes you were correct that worked perfectly for me :)